# Shared iCloud Folder

Tags: mac, icloud, sharing

I have a folder shared with me from another iCloud account. When I log into iCloud from a web browser I can see the shared folder. However when I'm on my Mac and I click on the iCloud folder I can not see the shared folder.

How can a Mac see shared folders in Finder locally as opposed to using a web app / browser?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens because your Mac is not fully updated. Ensure that you have the latest updates installed. As far as I recall, this particular feature requires 10.15.4, but upgrade to the latest 10.15.7 and check again.

By design, shared folders appear in Finder, so some delay or data corruption is usually the cause of not seeing the same folder structure in Finder as you see in the iCloud files web app.